# Resource view tab is missing - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio, tabs

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 installed on my notebook.
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 does have a Resource View tab (see the snapshot below)

[image]

Visual Studio Community 2022 does not (see the snapshot below)

[image]

I was trying to do different actions, but nothing helped so far.

What I was trying:

1. Window-->Reset Window Layout
2. To push button Show All Files in the Solution explorer menu
3. Remove and install again Visual Studio Community 2022

is that how it's meant to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal in Visual Studio to configure which windows / tabs / panes / etc. are open and visible at any one time.  I don't think there is anything wrong with your installation of VS.

You can open the Resource View pane from the View > Other Windows menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + E in solution explorer works according to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: This is accurate by default, although its possible for people to change keybindings in VS.  I've also had installed extensions change keybindings around. If someone tries this and it does not work, that could be one reason why.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on any of .rc files the Resource View tab appears immediately (see the snap shot below)
Case closed.

[image]
[image]